# Perché si omette l'articolo per alcuni sostantivi?

Tags: grammar

Perché si usa dire

> - *(La mia)* Mamma ha venduto l'auto.
> - *(Il mio)* Papà è andato dal barbiere.

Mentre, per riferirsi ad altri soggetti

> - La mia amica ha venduto l'auto.
> - Il mio amico è andato dal barbiere.

Il primo, in versione con gli articoli, mi suona strano, come se si volesse enfatizzare intensamente il ruolo e/o la possessione; eppure, come per il secondo, sono entrambi sostantivi. A mio intuito, è come se taluni rappresentassero una sorta di nome proprio: invero diciamo

> - Paolo è andato dal barbiere.

C'è dunque un qualche motivo? Mi viene il dubbio se è persino corretto formalmente.

Comment: Possibile duplicato: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/possessive-adjective-with-or-without-article-for-personal-relationships?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Mi sembra proprio di sì. Grazie @DenisNardin.